# Avoid scientific notation for scipy io.mmwrite function

Tags: python, file-io, scipy, format, sparse-matrix

I am trying to export a sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>, stored in the csr format, using from scipy: io.mmwrite, which is good at dealing with the sparseness of the data.
However, this output is in scientific notation:

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general
%
1719 2504 4304376
1 1 -9.0979224e-01
2 1 -1.6585451e-01
```

and I would like to obtain it in normal float number for a posttreatment script that expect classical float values in mtx format.

Is there a way to achieve this easily ?

My current solution involved to read again the written mtx file and convert for all lines the 3rd field, which is not time efficient...

Is there a way to specify scipy the notation to use ? Something like :

`np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`

I also tried out to force the conversion to double/float and could not find a related thread.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick hack that might work for you. (It's a hack because it overrides a private static method of a class that isn't really documented as part of the public API.  If the underlying code is changed in a future version of SciPy, this hack might no longer work.)

Create a subclass of `scipy.io.mmfile.MMFile` that overrides the `_field_template` method so that it returns a customized format string.  E.g.

```
from scipy.io.mmio import MMFile


class MMFileFixedFormat(MMFile):

    def _field_template(self, field, precision):
        # Override MMFile._field_template.
        return f'%.{precision}f\n'
```

To write a matrix market file with this class, replace your use of the function `scipy.io.mmwrite` with `MMFileFixedFormat().write`.

Here's an example in an ipython session.  The sparse matrix is in `a`.

```
In [77]: a
Out[77]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [78]: a.A
Out[78]: 
array([[0.27621606, 0.        , 0.        , 0.7780487 , 0.        ],
       [0.7295764 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.09457383, 0.        , 0.13346413, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.11267778, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.05113978, 0.        , 0.        , 0.9891698 , 0.        ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Here's the line that writes `a` to the file `"a.mtx"`.

```
In [79]: MMFileFixedFormat().write('a.mtx', a, precision=9)
```

Take a look at the file:

```
In [80]: !cat a.mtx                                                                                                 
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general
%
5 5 8
1 1 0.27621606
1 4 0.77804869
2 1 0.72957641
3 1 0.09457383
3 3 0.13346413
4 3 0.11267778
5 1 0.05113978
5 4 0.98916978
```

You might want to adjust the format string that is created in the function `_field_template()`.  A potential problem with a format that has a fixed number of decimal places is that if an entry has the value `0.00000098765432`, it will be printed as `0.000000099`, and `0.0000000000123` will be printed as `0.00000000` (assuming you used the same `precision` as in the example above).

---

Note, though, that a proper reader for a matrix market file should be able to handle numbers written in scientific notation.